# Struggling to save in 2 tables with hasOne association with cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I’m struggling with the hasOne association. Here are my 2 tables :

[image: database table rows]

Actually the ‘Etudiant’ (means student) has one User associated to it with the foreign key id present in both table which is the primary key of Users.

Here is the model EtudiantTable (student) :

```
class EtudiantTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('etudiant');
        $this->setDisplayField('ETUDIANT_ID');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('ETUDIANT_ID');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Maitredestage', [
            'foreignKey' => 'MAITREDESTAGE_ID',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->belongsToMany('Tuteuriut', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ETUDIANT_ID',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'TUTEURIUT_ID',
            'joinTable' => 'Suivre'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ID',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

And here is the add function in the EtudiantController :

```
public function add()
    {
        $etudiant = $this->Etudiant->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $etudiant = $etutable->patchEntity($etudiant, $this->request->data(), [
                'associated' => ['Users']
            ]);
            if ($this->Etudiant->save($etudiant)){
                $this->Flash->success(__('The etudiant has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The etudiant could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('etudiant'));
    }
```

And my usersTable model is like this :
`$this->belongsTo('Users', [ 'foreignKey' => 'ID', 'joinType' => 'INNER' ]);`

I want to do this : when i insert an Etudiant it inserts a new user and both have the same id.
But currently when i insert an Etudiant i get an error saying “no default value…id is empty” but the id is supposed to be inserted automatically.

I'm completely stuck so i need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any control over the schema of the etudiants table? Using ID as a foreign key instead of the primary is very confusing. Also, if I'm not mistaken, a "hasOne" relation means that the *other* table has a reference to this one; that is, your users table should have an ETUDIANT_ID column in it. If the relation is that the etudiants table needs to have the ID from the users table in it, then that should be a "belongsTo" relation.

Comment: Ok i changed my model etudiantTable to this 
`$this->belongsTo('Users', [
          'foreignKey' => 'id',
          'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    }`
The controller is the same but i still have the "ID is empty" error ;_;

Comment: I also made a hasOne relation in usersTable. btw i can change the schema of etudiants but not the one of useres

Comment: Either the `foreignKey` definition in your `belongsTo` should be `ID` (upper case), or (better, IMO) change the schema of etudiants to have lower-case field names.

Comment: And I still think that changing that column to `user_id` instead of just `id` would clarify things too.

Comment: Here is my actual code : 
`class UsersTable extends Table{

    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->hasOne('Etudiant', [
          'foreignKey' => 'ID',
        ]);
    }`
`class EtudiantTable extends Table{
    public function initialize(array $config){
      $this->belongsTo('Users', [
          'foreignKey' => 'ID',
          'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    }`
I will change id to user_id soon but it still doesn't work